# how to open particular tabView from click on menu list using JSF with primefaces and Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have no idea from how to open particular tabview click from menu list from header.xhtml page.
tabview is in another page in userprofile.xhtml page. In that page i have ajax call with particular listner. when i click on particular tab then i has been open perfertly. but i didn't have idea about clcicking from other page and render particular tabView.

I have to click from header.xhtml menu like Transaction History then that tab is open. if when i click on Change password then change password tab is open.

It is work from userprofile.xhtml page when i click on Transaction History then that tab is open. if when i click on Change password then change password tab is open. the issue with from menu item of ul li list it will not work.

I will show you code below with each file.

1.header.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{webUserBean.valid}">
                    <ul class="navlink-group link-group">
                        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                            id="memberLogin" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-expanded="false">Hello #{webUserBean.userName}</a>
                            <div class="user-icon d-none">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"
                                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <!-- <span class=""><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="line-height: 18px;"></i></span> -->
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="top-links-dropdown dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"
                                aria-labelledby="memberLogin">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Welcome</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="dropdown-form dd-user-loggedin">

                                            <ul class="navlink-group link-group">
                                                <li class="dropdown"><a class="nav-link" id="target" name="tabs"
                                                    href="my-transactions">Transaction History</a></li>

                                                <li class="dropdown"><a class="nav-link" id="target1" name="tabs"
                                                    href="edit-Profile">View/Edit Profile</a></li>

                                                <li class="dropdown"><a class="nav-link" id="target2" name="tabs"
                                                    href="reset-password-user">Change Password</a></li>

                                                <li><h:form>
                                                        <p:commandLink value="Sign Out" id="ajax" rendered="false"
                                                            action="#{signinController.logout}" ajax="false">
                                                        </p:commandLink>

                                                        <p:commandButton value="Sign Out" class="nav-link"
                                                            action="#{signinController.logout}"></p:commandButton>
                                                    </h:form></li>
                                            </ul>


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div></li>
                    </ul>
                </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

2.userprofile.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:common="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/common"
    template="/home.xhtml">
<p:tabView id="tab" activeIndex="#{panelDisplayBean.profileActiveTabIndex}" tabindex="#{panelDisplayBean.profileActiveTabIndex}">
                    <p:ajax event="tabChange"
                        listener="#{userDetailsController.onProfileTabChange}"
                        global="false" />
                    <p:tab id="tab1">
                    <ui:insert name="my-transactions">
                        <ui:include src="my-transactions.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab id="tab2">
                    <ui:insert name="edit-profile">
                        <ui:include src="edit-profile.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab id="tab3">
                    <ui:insert name="reset-password">
                        <ui:include src="reset-password.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>    
                    </p:tab>    
                </p:tabView> 
</ui:composition>
```

3.UserDetailsController.java

```
public void onProfileTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        UITabPanel tabView = (UITabPanel) event.getComponent();
        int activeTab = tabView.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab());
        logger.debug("tabView.getActiveIndex()=" + activeTab);
        panelDisplayBean.setProfileActiveTabIndex(activeTab);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have create one javascript and also put that function into each anchor tag like this and also added widgetWar into userprofile.xhtml in tabView.
2. Thanks @Jasper de Vries for give me idea for this. I have solve this problem by your code.

**1.header.xhtml**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function myTransactions() {
                     PF('tabPanelWidget').select($('#target' ).attr('data-value'));
                }
                function viewOrEditProfile() {
                    PF('tabPanelWidget').select($('#target1' ).attr('data-value'));
                }
                function chengePassword() {
                    PF('tabPanelWidget').select($('#target2' ).attr('data-value'));
                }       
            </script>
```

**header.xhtml**

```
<ul class="navlink-group link-group">
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="nav-link" id="target"
        href="my-transactions" onclick="myTransactions();" data-value="0">Transaction History</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a class="nav-link" id="target1"
        href="edit-Profile" onclick="viewOrEditProfile();" data-value="1">View/Edit Profile</a></li>

    <li class="dropdown"><a class="nav-link" id="target2"
        href="reset-password-user" onclick="chengePassword();" data-value="2">Change Password</a></li>

    <li><h:form>
            <p:commandLink value="Sign Out" id="ajax" rendered="false"
                action="#{signinController.logout}" ajax="false">
            </p:commandLink>

            <p:commandButton value="Sign Out" class="nav-link"
                action="#{signinController.logout}"></p:commandButton>
        </h:form></li>
</ul>
```